# Getting specific line from terminal output

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, stdout

"Hmm, I need to edit `file-i-must-edit-2`, but I cannot remember where it is."

```
locate file-i-must-edit
/home/user/file-i-must-edit-1
/home/user/file-i-must-edit-2
/home/user/file-i-must-edit-3
```

"Great! I wish there was a way to avoid typing `/home/user/file-i-must-edit-2` again..."

Is there a way to avoid typing
`nano /home/user/file-i-must-edit-2`
by typing something like `nano <output line 2>`?

Comment: If you are not adverse to mice, highlight and use button 3 -- this will copy the selected text to the cursor position on the command line.  It works in GUI terminals, and VTs if you have `gpm` installed and running.  If you don't have a third button, try both buttons simultaneously.

Comment: In addition to what @goldilocks suggests, see if a triple-left mouse click won't highlight the complete path and filename for you (if like me, you're a little clumsy with the mouse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get only one line of output, it's easy:

```
locate file-i-must-edit
nano $(!!)
```

There is a technique you can use when there are more lines, but it involves running the original command in a different way (which you may not want to do all the time):

```
$ touch a b c
$ OUT=( $(find .) )
$ echo ${OUT[2]}
./b
```

One thing you could do to avoid the typing is repeat the previous command (using readline, of course), narrow it down to get just one line, and then do `nano $(!!)` or pipe it to `xargs`.

Comment: Note that `OUT` is zero-based, so `${OUT[2]}` is the 3rd element.

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, but in my example the first element is `.`, so `./b` is the third (maybe you just commented to warn others, in which case, nevermind).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a programatic way to do it (vs. using the mouse for the X-Windows selection)

```
# function to nano edit a line (by number) from $list

nano-n() { nano "$(sed -n "$1{p;q}" <<<"$list")"; }

# As you produce your list of files, save them to a variable ($list), 
#   as well as printng them to the terminal.
# Do this by "duplicating" descriptor 1 (stdout) to 
#  another available descriptor (eg. 9)

exec 9>&1; list="$(locate file-i-must-edit |tee /dev/fd/9)"

# now you can just type the following at the propmt (assuming that $list is available at the prompt)  

nano-n 2
```